# Why does Document object not need to be cast when passing to XPathExpression.evalutate method?

Tags: java, xpath, parameter-passing

I'm doing some work cleaning up working code in an application of mine, and I noticed that I was reusing `XPathFactory`, `XPath`, `XPathExpression` objects in multiple places in my code, and figured I would clean it up and set up a method to do this. What I noticed is that typically when you send the XML document to the `XPathExpression.evalutate` method that you just place it in the parameter for the source like this.

```
DocumentBuilderFactory builderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
Document builder = builderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document document = builder.parse(new FileReader("/path/to/file.xml"));

XPathFactory factory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
XPath xpath = factory.newXPath();
XPathExpression expression = xpath.compile("path/to/node");
Object result = expression.evaluate(document, XPathConstants.NODE);
```

This is fine that it works but when I try to wrap the XPath portion into a separate method like this:

```
private Object getObjectByExpression(String expr, InputSource source, QName objectType)
{
    XPathFactory factory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
    XPath xpath = factory.newXPath();
    XPathExpression expression = xpath.compile(expr);
    Object result = expression.evaluate(document, objectType);
    return result;
}

public void someCalledMethod()
{
    DocumentBuilderFactory builderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    Document builder = builderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document document = builder.parse(new FileReader("/path/to/file.xml"));

    Object result = getObjectByExpression("/path/to/node", document, XPathConstants.NODE);
}
```

Eclipse tells me that I must cast the `document` to `InputSource` and marks it as an error. I did double check that the InputSource used in `XPathExpression.evaluate` and that in my method are the same class type. Does anyone have a deeper understanding as from where this inconsistency comes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, with `Document` it is using [`XPathExpression.evaluate(Object, QName)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/xpath/XPathExpression.html#evaluate(java.lang.Object,%20javax.xml.namespace.QName)) method.

[`Document`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Document.html) is an interface, so it can't heritate the class [`InputSource`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/xml/sax/InputSource.html). It is not possible. This is why you need to update your method :

```
private Object getObjectByExpression(String expr, Object source, QName objectType)
```

Or if you really want to limit this to `Document`

```
private Object getObjectByExpression(String expr, Document source, QName objectType)
```

Comment: Thanks @AxelH, I'm apparently blind and didn't see that there were multiple method signatures. I feel a bit dumb now.

Comment: @JRSofty With eclipse, you can use <ctrl> + left click on a method to open the declaration in the class. It is usefull to quickly check the method, or you just check the javadoc by hovering on the method, it would recognize that it is the `Object` method, not `InputSource` ;) I don't know the shortcut on other IDE

Comment: @JRSofty don't hesitate to mark an answer as accepted if it is solving your problem. Or feel free to wait for others ;)